# How to apply render texture(as target texture) on instantiated camera?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have a camera prefab which I instantiate 4 times in different locations where I want to add render texture(as target texture) on it so I could take the same texture and apply on a plane for monitoring in one of the scene. Please ask if it is not clear. I am trying to make a surveillance monitoring but do not know how to do this and I am stuck at this. please give examples Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the unity manual explains it very well https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html.

To be a bit more specific, here's a possible implementation:

Create some RenderTextures in the AssetFolder, than you have to link them to your Camera script to get them rendered. Add this file to your TextureRender-Camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera2Texture : MonoBehaviour {

public RenderTexture[] renderTextures;
private Camera cam;

private void Awake()
{
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RenderTexturesCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator RenderTexturesCoroutine()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < renderTextures.Length; i++)
    {
        // just move the camera a little bit and focus the center of the scene
        this.transform.position += Vector3.left * 2 * i;
        cam.transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);

        cam.targetTexture = renderTextures[i];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        cam.Render();
    }

    cam.targetTexture = null;
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

I start a coroutine which moves my TextureRender-Camera a little bit every second, put in the next RenderTexture from the array and render the image. At the end I disable the Camera. And this is the result when you put all 4 RenderTextures on Quads: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1WP4.png)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The camera is instantiated from a prefab. how do I get the render texture to the instantiated camera and apply on a surface for view.

Comment: You can just add your RenderTexture to your camera prefab (with the above script attached) in the Asset Window. When you instantiate the prefab it has the references to your RenderTextur assets. To Display the RenderTextures just add a Quad (or something else) and drag the RenderTexture on it to change its material. Once your camera has rendered you see the Texture on the quad.